# creating a macro to use in template

Tags: symfony, macros, twig

I'm trying to use macros to add some up and down arrows for the sorting in a table used with KnpPaginator.

i'm new to macros and the doc is a bit tedious for me, so I will try to explain and show what i've done.

I created a twig in my Macro folder called `icons.html.twig` that contains my macro

```
{% extends 'STBackofficeBundle::base.html.twig' %}

{% macro icon_class(type) %}
    {% set type_class = {
        sort: 'fa-angle-down'
    } %}
    {{ type_class[type] }}
{% endmacro %}
```

I imported it in my template

```
{% import "STBackofficeBundle:Macros:icons.html.twig" as icons %}
```

and tried to add it in a table header

```
<th>{{ icons.icon_class('sort') }}</th>
```

So it doesn't really work because it shows in string `fa-angle-down` instead of the icon itself. And when I try to remove the quotes i have an error. So I don't know what I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because currently you just print a class name.

```
<th>
    <i class="fa {{ icons.icon_class('sort') }}" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</th>
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works! :) I accepted your answer. I have one more question, what if when I sort while clicking, I want the arrow to change to `fa-angle-up` and when I click again it changes back to `fa-angle-down` ?

Comment: If you sort entires using JS, you should change class of the icon from `fa-angle-down` to `fa-angle-up` using JS.

If you do it using PHP controller, you should pass the sort parameter to URL and render appropriate icon in template according to that parameter.

Comment: i'm using KnpPaginator and I want to avoid using js as i'm using php. can't I do a condition with `if` in my macro for changing the arrow ? Do you have a simple example on how to do that easily ? because I don't quite understand what you trying to tell me